# Matplotlib - missing some ticks when sharing an axis between subplots

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib

I'm trying to make a figure consisting of 2 subplots with a shared y axis, however some 'ticks' are missing. An example:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import pandas as pd

df_a = pd.DataFrame({"Foo" : pd.Series(['A','B','C']), "Bar" : pd.Series([1,2,3])})
df_b = pd.DataFrame({"Foo" : pd.Series(['B','C','D']), "Bar" : pd.Series([4,5,6])})

fig, axes = plt.subplots(nrows=1, ncols=2, sharex= True, sharey=True)

df_a.plot.barh("Foo", "Bar", ax=axes[0], legend=False, title="df_a")
df_b.plot.barh("Foo", "Bar", ax=axes[1], legend=False, title="df_b")
```

produces the plot below (tick labels are mixed up):

[image]

What I was expecting to see is something like this (produced using R):

[image]

What am I missing here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need same indexes, so one possible solution is [`concat`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.concat.html):

```
df = pd.concat([df_a.set_index('Foo'), df_b.set_index('Foo')], axis=1)
df.columns = ['a','b']
print (df)
     a    b
A  1.0  NaN
B  2.0  4.0
C  3.0  5.0
D  NaN  6.0

df.a.plot.barh(ax=axes[0], legend=False, title="df_a")
df.b.plot.barh(ax=axes[1], legend=False, title="df_b")
```

Another solution is [`set_index`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.set_index.html) and [`reindex`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.reindex.html) by [`union`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Index.union.html) of `indexes`:

```
df_a = df_a.set_index('Foo')
df_b = df_b.set_index('Foo')
df_a = df_a.reindex(df_a.index.union(df_b.index))
df_b = df_b.reindex(df_a.index.union(df_b.index))
print (df_a)
     Bar
Foo     
A    1.0
B    2.0
C    3.0
D    NaN

print (df_b)
     Bar
Foo     
A    NaN
B    4.0
C    5.0
D    6.0



df_a.plot.barh( ax=axes[0], legend=False, title="df_a")
df_b.plot.barh( ax=axes[1], legend=False, title="df_b")
```

Comment: The `pd.concat` trick works like a charm and fits nicely with the rest of my workflow. Thanks!